# Get low power status in app

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uialertview, xcode7, ios9.1

I need to get low power mode status, weather low power mode is on or off alert in my app when iPhone change its power mode.

Please help me by getting the solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways for that.

1. You can register for Power State Notifications.

   `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(yourMethodName:) name:NSProcessInfoPowerStateDidChangeNotification object: nil];`
2. Or you can determine the current state.

   `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isLowPowerModeEnabled]`

The best thing what i think its really great for user experience point of view as per the `Apple` documentation is: Your app should take additional steps to help the system save energy when Low Power Mode is active. For example, your app could reduce the use of animations, lower frame rates, stop location updates, disable syncs and backups, and so on

I know there is already an answer for this (as per the comment dandan78) with links only no description, so posting bcoz it will be good if we have something here as well.

Comment: thank you very much @buntyMadan